# What is the "handle" for and where all handle are listed in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I have seen in many layout files with different handle in magento2:

like:

```
          <update handle="editor">
          <update handle="default"/>
```

and many more

So what is for the handle and where handles are defined?

I have read many blogs and question about handle but not exactly understood  functionality of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update handle node in layout files **includes** the `layout_file.xml` with the handle attribute's value (here in your example `editor.xml` and `default.xml`) in the current layout (like the `include_once` function of PHP) and executed recursively.

> For example, there is a file: app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_edit.xml

And there is a line `<update handle="customer_account"/>` which will include the file having name **customer_account.xml** in current layout rendering and execute it recursively.

So the `customer_account_edit.xml` will also have the css, js and the css selector classes added by the `customer_account.xml` (in short all layout changes) file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="custom.page.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Edit Account Information</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.additional" remove="true"/>

        <move element="customer_edit" destination="custom.account.wrapper" />
    </body>
</page>
```

> customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Theme::css/customer/customer-account.css" media="all" order="202" />
        <script src="Magento_Customer::js/customer-general.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="account"/>
        <attribute name="class" value="ve-customer-acc"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Dev doc reference: [Layout instructions > Update handle](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_upd)